# javascript execution exceeded timeout error in android tablet

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-emulator

I have an application in which i need to parse and display data from webservice. Here i have 2 different services, in one service i have 24 items and in another service i have 200 items. For service with 24 items i am able to display it properly but the service with 200 items showing **javascript execution exceeded timeout** error and displaying blank page.The code is same for both services. Can anyone please help me how to get rid of this error and display data properly?

I am adding piece of code here

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function showMessage(data, index) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
            if (index == "TrackDeals") {
                trackDeals(obj);
            } 
        }

        function OnError(request, status, error) {
            alert(request.statusText);
        }

        function trackDeals(trackdeals) {
            var items = [];
            var count = 0;
            $.each(trackdeals, function(key, value) {
                count++;
                pid = value.ApplicationId;
                var str = localStorage.getItem("appidlist");
                if (str == null){
                    var html = '<tr> my html code </tr>';
                } else {
                    var mySplitResult = str.split(",");
                    for(var i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
                        if(mySplitResult[i] == pid) {
                            var html = '<tr> my html code </tr>';
                        } else {
                            var html = '<tr> my html code </tr>';
                       }
                    }
                }
                items.push(html);
            });
            $('#trackdeals').html(items.join('')).trigger('create');
            $("table tr").slice(0, 5).show();
            $("#load").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("table tr:hidden").slice(0, 5).show();
                if ($("table tr:hidden").length == 0) {
                    alert("No more data");
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = "name";
            var trackparam = username + ',' + userid;
            CallWebServiceFromJquery('TrackDeals', trackparam);
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="deals-content">
                    <div class="deals-table-header">
                        <table width="100%" class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="18%">Reference Id</td>
                                <td width="22%">Account</td>
                                <td width="24%">Agency Name</td>
                                <td width="27%">Product</td>
                                <td width="8%"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="deals-table-content">
                        <table width="100%" class="deals-table-header-table" id ="trackdeals"></table>
                        <button id="load" style="width: 98%; font-weight: bold">Load More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

</body>
```

***Edit: I am able to get output for same code in gingerbread emulator but i am facing this error with honeycomb emulator.***

Comment: I realize this is for iOS, but the solution should work for Android, too.